# How do i serialize a JSchema as part of another object?

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I have an object who as a property that is a Json Schema (JSchema).

```
JSchema aSchema;

object foo = new {propA = "x", schema =  aSchema};
```

However, when this is serialized:

```
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
```

The JSchema object is serialized along with all its other properties ... and not a clean Json Schema, like the output of its ToString() which just emits the Json Schema string.

What I want is the schema property serialized as a Json Schema object like this:

```
{
    "propA": "x",
    "schema": {
        "id": "",
        "description": "",
        "definitions": {
            "number": {
                "type": "number"
            },
            "string": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "title": "Title",
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would you do this?

Comment: Would be helpful to see the output you are currently getting to understand the issue better.

Comment: Put your JSON Schema class OR put what output you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Number
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}
public class String
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}
public class Definitions
{
    public Number number { get; set; }
    public String @string { get; set; }
}
public class Title
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
public class Properties
{
    public Title title { get; set; }
}
public class Schema
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Definitions definitions { get; set; }
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public string propA { get; set; }
    public Schema schema { get; set; }
}
```

Serialize method

```
dynamic coll = new
{
    Root = new RootObject()
    {
        propA = "x",            
        schema = new Schema
        {   
            id = "",
            description = "",
            definitions = new Definitions()
            {
                number = new Number()
                {
                    type = "number"
                },
                @string  = new String()
                {
                    type = "number"
                }
            },
            properties = new Properties ()
            {
                title = new Title ()
                {
                    title = "Title",
                    type = "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(coll);
```

Fiddler: https://dotnetfiddle.net/f2wG2G

**Update**

```
var jsonSchemaGenerator = new JsonSchemaGenerator();
var myType = typeof(RootObject);

var schema = jsonSchemaGenerator.Generate(myType);
schema.Id = "";
schema.Description = "";
schema.Title = myType.Name;
```

Fiddler: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FwJX69

Comment: I understand how to create a Json output from a custom object like you show above.  However, as I mentioned in the post, i am working with a  JSchema object that has many other properties etc...

Comment: put your JSON Schema class.